VirtualBox, RockyLinux, Screen/Video Corrupted
Sorry, I don't know where to place this question.
I have Windows 10 Professional, and I would like to install Rocky Linux 9.3 in my machine using VirtualBox Version 7.0.14 r161095 (Qt5.15.2).
The problem as you can see, the image is corrupted.

Here my Specs (40GB for my HD)

Do you mind telling me what would be the problem?

Try unchecking "Enable 3d Acceleration" in your VMs Settings->Display.
The checkbox is at the bottom of the dialog just under the graphics Controller option box.
